# Ajax response 404 for @DeleteMapping

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, restful-url

I'm trying to make a ajax call to delete and get a new page in response. But facing 404 error.

```
<c:forEach items="${listLocation}" var="location">
<tr>
  <td>${location.id}</td>
  <td>${location.code}</td>
  <td>${location.name}</td>
  <td>${location.type}</td>
  <td><a href="deleteLocation?id=${location.id}" id="locID" onclick="return deleteRecord('${location.id}');">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Ajax call

```
function deleteRecord(locId) 
    {
        let contextURL = 'http://localhost:8080/LocationWeb/LocCon/deleteLocation/'
        let parmURL = contextURL + locId;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("DELETE", parmURL);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() 
        {
            if (xhr.status != 200) 
            {
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
            else
            {
              listAllPageCall();
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function()
        {
          console.log('NO CONNECTION');
        };
    }
    
    function listAllPageCall() 
    {
        let parmURL = 'http://localhost:8080/LocationWeb/LocCon/listAllLocations/'
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", parmURL);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() 
        {
            if (xhr.status != 200) 
            {
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Called');
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function()
        {
          console.log('NO CONNECTION');
        };
    }
```

**Spring Boot code flow**

This is to call the webpage to be displayed

```
@GetMapping("/listAllLocations")
public String displayLocations(ModelMap resModMap)
{
    List<Location> listLocation = locationService.getAllLocation();
    resModMap.addAttribute("listLocation", listLocation);
    return "displayAllLocations";
}
```

This is to delete and call the webpage like above one. Both response are same. But still getting the white lable error 404

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteLocation/{id}")
public String deleteLocation(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap resModMap)
{
    //Location location = locationService.getLocationByID(id);
    Location location = new Location();
    location.setId(id);
    locationService.deleteLocation(location);
    List<Location> listLocation = locationService.getAllLocation();
    resModMap.addAttribute("listLocation", listLocation);
    return "displayAllLocations";
}
```

Delete is happening. Only the page is not getting displayed on response. Please help me.

I tried this way. By calling the get function in return. But no luck

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteLocation/{id}")
public void deleteLocation(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap resModMap)
{
    //Location location = locationService.getLocationByID(id);
    Location location = new Location();
    location.setId(id);
    locationService.deleteLocation(location);
    displayLocations(resModMap);
}
```

Checked in debug, its getting into

```
xhr.onerror = function()
{
   console.log('NO CONNECTION');
};
```

[image]

Should I get response as webpage? Anything like that should be added?

[image]

Tried @RequestMapping, this works good.

```
@RequestMapping("deleteLocation")
public void deleteLocation(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap resModMap)
{
    //Location location = locationService.getLocationByID(id);
    Location location = new Location();
    location.setId(id);
    locationService.deleteLocation(location);
    List<Location> listLocation = locationService.getAllLocation();
    resModMap.addAttribute("listLocation", listLocation);
    return "displayAllLocations";
}
```

In jsp

```
<td><a href="deleteLocation?id=${location.id}">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: You have an extra slash in: `let parmURL = 'http://localhost:8080/LocationWeb/LocCon/listAllLocations/'`. If you remove that, does it resolve your issue? Depending if your router is sensitive to that, it might cause your problem

Comment: In deletRecord() itself in xhr.send(); its getting in to that 404 page.

Comment: You mean both functions do the right thing but you get redirected to a 404 page? I see that your anchor link forwards the user to: `href="deleteLocation?id=${location.id}"`. So it forwards the user to (GET) `/deleteLocation`. Does this path exist? If you want to not forward the user, you could just do `<a href="#trigger"`. This will trigger the functions, but not update your page.

Comment: Yeah I can do this way. But I'm trying to go with Ajax call. Let me see whether this href works correctly. Please give me a moment.4

Comment: `<td><a href="deleteLocation?id=${location.id}">Delete</a></td>` I tried this way now. Didn't work. Something is wrong with the mappin I guess. Because deletion is happening at the backend.

Comment: No this  didn't even delete. I checked the console log. Previous thing made delete function. Only the page was not displayed.